# svg to canvas -- opera

Tags: html, svg, html5-canvas, opera

I have this code which works fine in Chromium and Firefox, but Opera does not fire the load event, because it cannot deal with the image data. If I set the data to a regular jpeg it works fine, but not with the svg. Is there any fix?

```
var img = new Image();

var that = this;

img.onload = function(){ onCacheCreated.call( that, img ); }

img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," 
    + btoa( ( new XMLSerializer() ).serializeToString( this._dom ) );
```

Comment: See here for a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TtEvM/3/  (change img src to jpg/png etc to see image on canvas in Opera)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, quite an interesting range of behaviour shown all round here.

The part that makes it especially interesting, is that it actually *can* load the SVG.
I tried it both as a base64 encoded string appended to `"data:image/svg+xml;base64,"`
and as plain-text, appended to `"data:image/svg+xml,"`

The 'neat' part is - the onload event never fires. however, if we create an img element and add it to the page, we can see it displayed when loaded. But again, we never got an onload event from it.

What's even stranger: when I use a logo with a transparent shadow, gradients and blurring, the gradients, blurring & shadow dont work, BUT only when sent as plain-text.

Stranger again, Chrome displays them both identically, IE9 shows the base64 version only, Opera shows both, but with a very different appearance.

Perhaps you could set an interval timer, then check the dimensions of the img element being loaded. One would suppose that they would be different before and after loading. I'd have to check to see if this would be a viable alternative to handling the (never-fired) onload event.

Here's the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
<script>
function myInit()
{
    var img = new Image();
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    var imgStr = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,";
    imgStr += "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";
    img.src = imgStr;

    img = new Image();
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    var imgStr = "data:image/svg+xml,";
    imgStr += '<svg   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"   width="85"   height="85">  <defs     id="defs4172">    <radialGradient       inkscape:collect="always"       xlink:href="#linearGradient4899"       id="radialGradient4907"       cx="219.63432"       cy="53.499279"       fx="219.63432"       fy="53.499279"       r="15.890625"       gradientTransform="matrix(-3.2783033,-0.72853385,0.69995344,-3.1496954,739.17321,345.31995)"       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" />    <linearGradient       id="linearGradient4899">      <stop         style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;"         offset="0"         id="stop4901" />      <stop         style="stop-color:#f7b4b4;stop-opacity:1;"         offset="1"         id="stop4903" />    </linearGradient>    <linearGradient       inkscape:collect="always"       xlink:href="#linearGradient4914"       id="linearGradient4920"       x1="216.71745"       y1="-52.048553"       x2="215.80347"       y2="85.141525"       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"       gradientTransform="translate(-165.25951,-15.946439)" />    <linearGradient       inkscape:collect="always"       id="linearGradient4914">      <stop         style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:1;"         offset="0"         id="stop4916" />      <stop         style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:0;"         offset="1"         id="stop4918" />    </linearGradient>    <filter       color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"       inkscape:collect="always"       id="filter5096">      <feGaussianBlur         inkscape:collect="always"         stdDeviation="0.55645637"         id="feGaussianBlur5098" />    </filter>    <filter       color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"       inkscape:collect="always"       id="filter5076">      <feGaussianBlur         inkscape:collect="always"         stdDeviation="1.2507933"         id="feGaussianBlur5078" />    </filter>  </defs>  <g     inkscape:label="Layer 1"     inkscape:groupmode="layer"     id="layer1">    <path       id="path4922"       d="m 23.770467,50.684151 c -16.7517702,2.0478 -24.38592023,11.1113 -17.0842902,20.2355 7.3016202,9.1241 26.7788002,14.8597 43.5305702,12.812 16.75177,-2.0477 24.4273,-11.1024 17.12568,-20.2266 -7.30163,-9.1242 -26.82019,-14.8686 -43.57196,-12.8209 z m 0.7197,0.8994 c 8.76334,-1.0712 21.4925,5.0463 28.40462,13.6737 l -15.89611,1.957 15.90625,-1.9444 c 6.90889,8.6334 5.37076,16.5033 -3.39774,17.5751 -8.7685,1.0719 -21.47462,-5.0567 -28.38351,-13.6901 -6.90889,-8.6335 -5.40201,-16.4995 3.36649,-17.5713 z"       style="opacity:0.31858407;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;filter:url(#filter5076)"       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />    <path       style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"       d="m 50.365497,2.5223006 c -16.75177,0 -30.3125,18.2710704 -30.3125,40.7812504 0,22.5102 13.56073,40.75 30.3125,40.75 16.75177,0 30.34375,-18.2398 30.34375,-40.75 0,-22.51018 -13.59198,-40.7812504 -30.34375,-40.7812504 z m 0,2.21875 c 8.76334,0 15.89895,17.2443904 15.90625,38.5313004 l -15.90625,0.031 15.90625,0 c 0,21.2994 -7.13775,38.5625 -15.90625,38.5625 -8.7685,0 -15.875,-17.2631 -15.875,-38.5625 0,-21.29946 7.1065,-38.5625504 15.875,-38.5625504 z"       id="path4887"       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />    <path       style="fill:url(#radialGradient4907);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"       d="m 50.365497,4.7410506 c -8.7685,0 -15.875,17.2630904 -15.875,38.5625004 0,21.2994 7.1065,38.5625 15.875,38.5625 8.7685,0 15.90625,-17.2631 15.90625,-38.5625 l -2.375,0 c 0,20.2853 -6.07148,36.7188 -13.53125,36.7188 -7.45977,0 -13.5,-16.4335 -13.5,-36.7188 0,-20.28534 6.04023,-36.7500004 13.5,-36.7500004 7.45538,0 13.52504,16.4453704 13.53125,36.7188004 l 2.375,0 c -0.007,-21.28691 -7.14291,-38.5313004 -15.90625,-38.5313004 z"       id="path4891"       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />    <path       style="fill:url(#linearGradient4920);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;filter:url(#filter5096)"       d="m 50.365497,2.5223006 c -16.75177,0 -30.3125,18.2710704 -30.3125,40.7812504 0,2.6379 0.20673,5.2206 0.5625,7.7188 4.50164,3.8753 9.71309,6.9082 15.4375,8.8125 -0.98384,-5.0181 -1.5625,-10.6024 -1.5625,-16.5313 0,-21.29941 7.1065,-38.5625004 15.875,-38.5625004 8.76334,0 15.89895,17.2443904 15.90625,38.5313004 l -15.90625,0.031 15.90625,0 c 0,5.9276 -0.54431,11.5139 -1.53125,16.5312 5.71636,-1.9046 10.94127,-4.9418 15.4375,-8.8125 0.35653,-2.4981 0.53125,-5.0808 0.53125,-7.7187 0,-22.51023 -13.59198,-40.7813004 -30.34375,-40.7813004 z"       id="path4909"       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />  </g></svg>';
    img.src = imgStr;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='myInit();'>

</body>
</html>
```